# What is this custom of chasidim to say tehillim after maariv chol hamoed Sukkos?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, sukkot

I see a chasidic minyon that has been saying tehillim with a specific niggun every night of chol hamoed after maariv,‎ it seems like a well known practice,‎ does anyone know what it is?‎

Comment: Which tehillim?

Comment: שיר המעלות is starred after stopping pirke avot

Comment: I'm remembering the chorus was ושאבתם מים בששון

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went and asked the Gabbai of the minyon,‎ which was difficult because we didn't have a fluent shared language,‎ but it sounds like he thinks many communities Chasidish‏/‏‎Litvish‏/‏‎Yerushalmi all have a custom of reading after Maariv the 15 Shir Hamaalot tehilim on chol hamoed in imitation of the order they were read in the Beis Hamikdash.‎ He says all communities he is aware of have the same niggun,‎ which I would like to find but haven't been able to yet.‎ Thanks for the suggested answers!

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/13-01-12/

Comment: Thanks for the source @JoelK ! Now I'll try to find the niggun that was used,‎ it was very interesting.‎

Answer (score 1):

Many *chasidim* recite a psalm after *maariv* (before "*Alenu*") every weekday. Normally, it's psalm 121, but on *chol hamoed Sukos* it's 122, and I'm guessing some sing it and that's what you heard. (On  *chol hamoed Pesach* it's 114.)